# how to config ember.js and nodejs with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js

how to config ember.js and nodejs with ruby on rails? I am getting following error,

> The Broccoli Plugin: [object Object] failed with:
>
> Error: watch ENOSPC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get running with your Rails environment.

```
rails new myApp
```

Now, clean up the Gemfile.

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'ember-cli-rails'
```

You can install the dependencies with `bundle install`.

We've got a generator from Ember gem. Let's create initializer file with that.

```
rails g ember-cli:init
```

By default, it’s configured to use an application called frontend that must live under `app/frontend`.

```
root 'frontend#index'
```

you may change it to

```
get '/*path' => 'frontend#index'
```

Create the controller FrontendController with index method. We'll need the view as well. Create a empty view for index method inside app/views/frontend/index.html.erb I would like to have a separate layout as well. You might want to use the default layout with other things. So create the file app/views/layouts/frontend.html.erb with below content.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'frontend' %>
  <%= include_ember_script_tags :frontend %>
</head>

<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't forget to create the app/assets/stylesheets/frontend.css file and add it to Rails asset pipeline. Open config/initializers/assets.rb and add this line:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( frontend.css )
```

We've the ember command from Node. We'll use that to initialize our Ember App.

```
ember new frontend --skip-git
```

This will create our app. Go to the frontend directory, we'd need to more npm package. also install :

```
`ember install ember-cli-rails-addo`
```

Okay, now start the server `rails s`

Credited to [baber.im](https://www.babar.im/blog/programming/ruby/setup-rails-with-ember-cli-and-emblem.html#sthash.jFGkvbsq.dpuf) and [nandovieira](http://nandovieira.com/setting-up-emberjs-with-rails-ember-cli-edition). Thank you guys.